# How do I think and act in Require.js if I have a <script src="..."> background and a Django backend?

Tags: django, npm, commonjs

I started and stopped asking several questions to help me get (in the immediate need) [react-tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip), which does not advertise a non-CommonJS distribution. But I expect to want to do other things that call for CommonJS.

I know how to include packages in Node, but I found myself starting to ask various XY-like questions about implementation.

What can / should I do to my Django backend so I can, in the first instance:

```
var reacttooltip = require('react-tooltip');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to your Django backend unless you want to have Django compile your CSS and JavaScript for you (by using [django-pipeline](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)).

What you want to look into is using more modern front-end tooling, like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) and [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or stick to Make for building your front-end project.

Furthermore, what you want to have in your `<script>` tags is a bundled JavaScript file compiled with above tools in which you boot your JavaScript application.

Comment: Is there a HOWTO on using webpack and gulp when not using Node/io as server? Some of the documentation seems to be WIP even in covering nuts and bolts: http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html